# Put Condition on Authentication Providers

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, ldap

I am using spring security 5.7.11 and I have the following code.I am able to do the authentication using database and using ldap when using alone how to make it based on condition.For example if auth.type=ldap then use ldap else use the database  .

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {


    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new MuserDetailsService();
    }


    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(12);
    }
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationSuccessHandler customAuthenticationSuccessHandler() {
        return new CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
    }
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider(){
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider=new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authenticationProvider;
    }
    @Autowired
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .ldapAuthentication()
                .userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=people")
                .groupSearchBase("ou=groups")
                .contextSource()
                    .url("ldap://localhost:8389/dc=springframework,dc=org")
                    .and()
                .passwordCompare()
                    .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder())
                    .passwordAttribute("userPassword");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `@ConditionalOnProperty` on your Configuration-classes

example:

```java
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix="auth", name="type", havingValue="db", matchIfMissing=true)
// default configuration due to matchIfMissing=true
public class DataBaseSecurityConfig {
 // your DB related Beans
}

/* and */

@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix="auth", name="type", havingValue="ldap")
public class LdapBaseSecurityConfig {
 // your LDAP related Beans
}
```

Or `@ConditionalOnProperty` a on `@Bean`

example:

```java
 @Bean
 @ConditionalOnProperty(prefix="auth", name="type", havingValue="db", matchIfMissing=true)
 //Bean creation if auth.type=db or auth.type is not provided
  public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider(){
    ...;
 }
```

Or you can use `@Value`

example: *@Value("${auth.type:db}")* where "db" is the default value if no value is provided

```java
@Autowired
public void configure(@Value("${auth.type:db}") String type, AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth){
 if("db".equals(type) {
  ....
 } else {
  ....
 }
}
```